# Is Bitcoin vulnerable to a Birthday Attack against Private Keys?

Tags: security, private-key

[This is a definition of the Birthday Attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack).

Someone claims Bitcoin is vulnerable to such an attack in the bitcoin IRC chat.

Are they correct?